# A 'semi random' AR model

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two sets of AR model parameters.
Let $(Y_n, 0\leq n\leq N)$ be a time sequence, and let $T\subset [0,1,...,N]$ be a set of times.
The time series is defined as follows:
$$\begin{cases} Y_n=\sum_{i=0}^k \phi_i Y_{n-i} + \varepsilon_n, n\in T\\
Y_n=\sum_{i=0}^k \psi_i Y_{n-i} + \varepsilon_n, n\notin T
 \end{cases} $$
where $\varepsilon_n$ is some i.i.d sequence. That is, the process is defined using two AR-type parameters, chosen by the set T. Denote this model as Model A.

Now, consider the case in which $T$ is not known but is estimated from the data, say by another time sequence, $Z_n$, and we have $\hat{T}(\{Z_n\})$ as an estimator for the (random) set $T$. Denote this model as model B.

I was wondering if any of these models are known in the literature, since they aren't strictly AR, etc. I'm looking to estimate their parameters in some sense.

Thanks

Comment: Markov switching? Or, if $T$ were, say, $0,\ldots,\tau N$, $\tau\in(0,1)$, a structural break in the AR coefficients.

Comment: *Threshold AR models* [SETAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SETAR_%28model%29) are an alternative approach to model regime switching parameters. Time-varying parameters can also be modeled as *polynomial splines*; this could capture smooth changes throughout time in the parameters, these changes are not necessarily related to recurrent regimes. In seasonal data, e.g., quarterly data,  *periodic autoregressive models* are sometimes used; there, the AR coefficients change with the seasons.

Comment: SETAR models, as far as I understand, assume that the data are'piecewise AR', that there are compact supports in which the process is an AR with the same parameters. While similar, in my case I need only two models, but the AR switching might not be compactly supported. i.e. there can be many 'switching' events, and for each one, the model at that time belongs to either of the two models.

Comment: It seems that Markov switching models already mentioned by ChristophHanck fit your description. A popular reference is [Hamilton (1989)](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1912559), which proposes a model with a switching mean; in principle it can be adapted to switches in the AR coefficients. The model can be fitted for example following the algorithm given in that reference or by means of Gibbs sampling.